# Declaratively select an entity requiring relations from all (dynamic number of) related entities

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, dynamic-sql, relational-division, query-performance

I am trying to construct a where clause that requires an X number of children to have a relation to a specific parent with a N-to-N relationship. Something similar to "Get all receipts where these products were sold together."
An example scenario is easier to explain:

```
DECLARE @Nodes TABLE(
  Id INT
);

DECLARE @Arc TABLE(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  Source INT, -- FK @Nodes.Id
  Dest INT    -- FK @Nodes.Id
);

INSERT INTO @Nodes (Id) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

INSERT INTO @Arc (Source, Dest) VALUES
   (1, 2)
  ,(1, 3)
  ,(1, 3)
  ,(2, 1)
  ,(2, 3)
  ,(2, 4);
```

In the SP, the input is preprocessed into a table like this:

```
DECLARE @InputConnectedNodes TABLE ( Id INT );
INSERT INTO @InputConnectedNodes (Id) VALUES (3),(4); -- not a fixed number of nodes
```

In this example we want all nodes that have an arc to nodes 3 and 4 (only node 2 in the above example).
Currently we have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Source 
    FROM @Arc
    WHERE Dest IN (SELECT Id FROM @InputConnectedNodes);
```

Then we have some ugly procedural code that loops through the input and (nested) output checking for all relationships. I'd like to replace it with something declarative. The best I came up with so far is this:

```
SELECT Source 
    FROM @Arc 
    WHERE Dest IN (SELECT Id FROM @InputConnectedNodes) 
    GROUP BY Source
    HAVING COUNT(Source) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @InputConnectedNodes)
```

But it will fail when nodes have multiple (identical) arcs like (1->3) in my example.

I could also solve this by dynamically generating a where clause, but I'd prefer a fully declarative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest loosening your resolve for a fully declarative solution. There may not be a declarative way to solve your problem, and there are many cases where dynamic SQL is a much better solution in terms of performance - even if it lacks readability.

Dynamic SQL gives the optimizer the opportunity to use different plans optimized for different parameters instead of having to come up with a single plan that solves all permutations well. The latter is quite difficult to achieve.

Your problem is called [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division). See questions in that tag and:

- [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) by Joe Celko; and
- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364969) on Stack Overflow.

Most of the Stack Overflow solutions would work as they are, or with minor modifications for SQL Server. Note how the more complicated queries, with multiple joins or `EXISTS` subqueries (that would need dynamically produced code for the arbitrary cases) are more efficient than the `GROUP BY` query.